# How to read header location using $resource

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I'm trying read headers location using `$resource` in AngularJS.

Output:

```
headers()
Object {}No Properties 

var Devices = $resource(':deviceId', null, {
    save: {
        method: 'POST'
    }
}

function abcadd(customerId, devices) { 
    var headers = {};
    headers = { 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Location' }
    var parameters = {
        $headers: headers,
        customerId: customerId
    };
    return Devices.save(parameters, devices, function (data, headers) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(headers());
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried                   save: {
                      method: 'POST'//,
                      //interceptor: {
                      //    response: function (response) {
                      //        response.resource.httpHeaders = response.headers;
                      //        return response.resource;
                      //    }
                      //}
                  },

Comment: Browsers only honor  an [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header if it is sent from a server. Only the server can get the browser to relax [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) protections.